# How to install packages within pbuilder/cowbuilder chroot environment?

Tags: package-management, chroot, pbuilder

I want to do some automation of building/installing packages. I know cowbuilder allows you to build a package in a clean chroot environment.

Is there a way to *install* built packages to make sure dependencies are met?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/var/cache/pbuilder/hooks` file to install missing packages in chroot via package manager.